# How can I set the login_required in a dispatcher middleware on flask?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I am usin the wsgi DispatcherMiddleware in order to prefix a url on my appl

here is my app

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = '/'
login_manager.login_message_category = "info"
```

Here is my dispatcher code

```
disp_app = DispatcherMiddleware(app, {"/dash": dash_app_seg.server})
run_simple("127.0.0.1", 5000, disp_app, use_debugger=True)
```

How can I specify to the urls that the imported app needs to have a authenticated user, cause I have the annotation of @login_required but I don't know how to specify it into the dispatcher middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can search of all the views that your app contains and set the login_required like this

```
for view_func in app.view_functions:
   # add some validations
   app.view_functions[view_func] = login_required(app.view_functions[view_func])
```

please check it